# Sets problem with upper bounds

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have come across this problem in my discrete mathematics class and I have no clue how to go about it since I haven't dealt with upper bounds before in sets.  If anyone could help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it.

In the special case S = {1, 2, 3, 4}, there exists two sets A,B that are elements of P(S) such that {A,B}  has no upper bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your ordering. It seems safe to assume that you mean membership (i.e. $A \leq B \Leftrightarrow A \subseteq B$). In that case it seems like there are many sets $A,B$ that satisfy the condition that $A,B \in P(S)$ and $\{A,B\}$ has no upper bounds. For instance $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

What order are you considering?  The natural one would be to order the subsets by inclusion.  In this case, $S$ is an upper bound for $P(S)$.  But if $A$ and $B$ are elements of $P(S)$, then $\{A,B\}$ looks something like $\{\{2\},\{3\}\}$ and is not in $P(S)$